# Is there a standard or preferred tag type for adding additional anchor / fragment links to a location?

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor, semantic-markup, url-fragment

I currently have an `id` attribute on each section heading in a HTML document, so that URLs can be generated with a hash fragment that links directly to that section in the document. For example:

```
<h2 id="section3.4">Section 3.4 - Foo</h2>
```

This would, of course, be linked as `page.html#section3.4`.

I would like to offer an alternative formatting for that fragment, e.g. `page.html#s3.4`. The exact formatting is arbitrary and not important here.

Obviously one cannot simply apply multiple ID tags to a single HTML element in order to achieve this. The solution, it seems, is to add a secondary tag to the page at the same position as the heading, e.g.:

```
<h2 id="section3.4">Section 3.4 - Foo</h2><xyz id="s3.4"></xyz>
```

Is there a standard or preferred tag type that is used for this purpose? Searching around, I was surprised to find no "best practice" answer for this.

Technically the tag type is arbitrary, since any element with an `id` attribute should work, but picking `canvas` or `script`, for example, is clearly silly. I've seen `a` suggested, but I'm not sure that is semantically correct, since `a` is supposed to create an anchor *to* a location, not *be* a location.

One thought I had was to have the enclosing `section` tag's ID be the target, but that doesn't enable an arbitrary number of alternate fragment names, and technically it isn't linking to the same location since the bounding box is subject to CSS.

I feel like the ideal element would be one that is guaranteed to have no visual presence on the DOM, hold the same vertical position as the adjacent element, have no side effects, and which makes semantic sense as a positional marker, all while also not having any impact on accessibility (e.g. screenreaders). However, I cannot think of such an element. Is there a standard that I missed? If not, which tag might be the best option?

Answer (score 0):

In inline contexts, use a `<span>` element wrapping the text inside the appropriate heading.

```
<h2 id="section3.4"><span id="s3.4">Section 3.4 - Foo</span></h2>
```

In block contexts, use a `<div>`.

Both are semantically neutral. And this approach ensures the heading text receives appropriate focus regardless of which fragment identifier is used.

Comment: Do spans inherently modify the box model boundaries or layout behaviours of a contained element in any way, even if the contained elements are themselves implicitly or explicitly styled?

Comment: No, there's no default styles associated with them.

Comment: That appears to be incorrect. Spans are inline elements, so while they don't have any default CSS applied, they do implicitly end up with `display: inline`. This modifies the layout behaviour of contained elements based on [the box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model). A span is fine if you know every child element is also inline, but it will modify the layout behaviour of block, inline-block, flex, etc. child elements. Same goes for div. Neither are completely layout-neutral.

Comment: To be clear, I know that in this case putting a span inside the h2 is absolutely fine as a solution, and it will work, and it won't cause problems unless the page includes CSS that styles all span elements. But it isn't strictly a semantically-correct catch-all solution for linking to a specific element's position with two different fragment names, since adding a container inherently changes layout behaviour, even if that behaviour is subtle or invisible in practice. What I was hoping for is an element type that is effectively transparent to the DOM, with no impact on layout, ARIA role, etc.

Comment: There is no single element like that. The closest is `<span>` in inline contexts and `<div>` in block contexts. Aside from their inherent `display` styles, they are transparent in terms of layout, semantics, role, etc.

Comment: Indeed, that does appear to be the closest approach in practice. Ideally this would be resolved with a HTML standard amendment that introduces an attribute for alternative anchor names (and, more ideally still, we would never have used the `id` attribute for this from the start the start, since machine identification of DOM elements and linking to page sections are fundamentally different functions).

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect inline and block contexts.